# javascript select box values not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hoping you can please help.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select id='bonus1frequency'>
<option value="0">Annual</option>
<option value="1">Half Yearly</option>
<option value="2">Quarterly</option>
</select>
```

Depending on what option is selected, fields are displayed in a divider. For example if you select annual, a field to enter annual bonus is displayed. If you select 'Half Yearly' two fields to enter two half yearly bonuses are displayed.

The trouble I'm having is that if you select 'Half yearly' for example, then enter what the half yearly bonus into the fields, then you change your mind and decide you want to enter an annual bonus instead, the values that you enter into the half yearly bonus are retained. I need them to be set to zero when you switch between options in the html select box.

I tried the following code to help with this but it's not working and i'm not sure why. All it does is prevent me from putting anything at all into the half year boxes.

```
var bonus_val_1 = document.getElementById("bonus1frequency");
var strUser = bonus_val_1.options[bonus_val_1.selectedIndex].value;

 if  (strUser = "0") //if annual bonus is selected
 {

  document.getElementById("halfyear_bonus_one").value = 0.00;

}
```

Edit:

I'm using the following JQUERY in the main HTML document to actually switch what fields are displayed when the user selects each option. So if the user selects option value 0 'annual' in the select box, the following code will show the annual bonus divider containing the annual bonus field, and hide the dividers that show half yearly and quarterly bonus fields.

Based on comments about how I need to tie resetting these fields to the change event, I just thought maybe I can reset the fields to zero within the following jquery code. However I'm even less familiar with JQUERy and not sure how to do that...any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#bonus1frequency').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '0')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#annual").show();
         $("#halfyearly").hide();
          $("#quarterly").hide();

      }
       if ( this.value == '1')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#annual").hide();
         $("#halfyearly").show();
          $("#quarterly").hide();

      }
```

### EDIT 2

I have updated the code as follows:

```
$('#bonus1frequency').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#annual").show();
         $("#halfyearly").hide();
          $("#quarterly").hide();
          $("#halfyear_bonus_one").val("0");
```

This prevents me from entering a value into the halfyear bonus one field. It just keeps resetting the value to zero. I've added an empty 'choose' option to the select box but it hasn't made a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: `0.00;` is just going to be `0` and you are not doing a comparison. `strUser = "0")` <---

Comment: Are you sure of your if statement? I think should be if (strUser === "0").

Comment: Thanks that lets me enter a value into the half year bonus fields however the value is still retained when I switch back to annual bonus using the html select box

Comment: Code is partially clear. Have you written this code in jquery event 'change'?

Comment: At the moment I also have the following jquery that enables me to show / hide the fields depending on what the user has selected in the drop down box:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following for help and add code for quarterly. Use jquery instead of using javascript code to get elements.

```
<select id="bonus1frequency">
<option value="0">Annual</option>
<option value="1">Half Yearly</option>
<option value="2">Quarterly</option>
</select>

<div id="annual" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" id="a1">
</div>
<div id="half" style="display: block;">
  <input type="text" class="b2">
  <input type="text" class="b2">
  <script>
    $('#half').hide()//Same as this hide quarterly div
    $("#bonus1frequency").change(function(){
      var strUser = $(this).val()

    if (strUser === "0") //if annual bonus is selected
    {
      $('#annual').show()
      $('#half').hide()
      $(".b2").val(0);
    }else{
      $('#half').show()
      $('#annual').hide()
      $('#a1').val(0)
    }
    })
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use same for Quarterly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Finally got it working with the above answer thanks so much :o)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're not binding it to the select's change event. It will run when loading the page, and since the default option in the dropdown is "Annual", the value which will appear as the value of #halfyear_bonus_one would be 0.00 and won't change, even if the user will choose another option in the dropdown.

You should create a js function which contain your code (with few corrections)
and then bind it to a change event of the dropdown.
Moreover, you should add conditions to handle the other scenarios: "half yearly" and "quarterly".

```
var bonusval1 = document.getElementById("bonus1frequency");
bonusval1.onchange = function () {
        var strUser = bonusval1.options[bonusval1.selectedIndex].value;
    if  (strUser == "0"){ //if annual bonus is selected
          document.getElementById("halfyear_bonus_one").value = "0.00";
    } else if(strUser == 1){ //Half yearly is selcted
          document.getElementById("halfyear_bonus_one").value = "1.00";    
    } else { //quertly is selected
          document.getElementById("halfyear_bonus_one").value = "2.00";    
    }
}
```

Now, there's another problem - the default value is the first value - but the "onchange" event won't trigger. We can run the function outside of the onchange event in order to handle the default value **or** you can add a blank option to the dropdown as the first option, something like "Choose:" or whatever.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqkfp06h/)

**Regarding the second question**
I didn't understand why would you use jQuery all of a sudden when you already
wrote pretty good js code. Those kind of decisions should be considered in the beginning of the process.

Anyway, You can use the `.val()` function to change the value of the input fields. I don't have the code of your form and the dividers but it should be pretty much like the following:

```
  if ( this.value == '0')
  //.....................^.......
  {
    $("#annual").show();
     $("#halfyearly").hide();
      $("#quarterly").hide();
    $("#id_of_input_for_halfyearly").val("0");
    $("#id_of_input_for_quarterly").val("0");

  }
```

Comment: Hi Ofir,Is there anything I can add to my jquery code to reset the values in jquery '$('#bonus1frequency').on('change', function() { if ( this.value == '0') //.....................^....... { $("#annual").show(); $("#halfyearly").hide(); $("#quarterly").hide(); }'

Comment: Are you using jQuery or JS? Can you edit your main question and add your last question? What do you mean by saying "reset the values in jquery" ?

Comment: I related to your second question in my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks I've tried it but it still doesn't work - I'll edit my main answer again.

Comment: To be honest - it's really hard to understand what you want. Can you please add an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you out.

```
jQuery('#bonus1frequency').on('change',function(){
    if(this.value==1){
        jQuery('.yearly').val('').show();
        jQuery('.half-yearly').val(0).hide();
        jQuery('.quarterly').val(0).hide();
    }else if(this.value==2){
        jQuery('.yearly').val(0).hide();
        jQuery('.half-yearly').val('').show();
        jQuery('.quarterly').val(0).hide();
    }else if(this.value==3){
        jQuery('.yearly').val(0).hide();
        jQuery('.half-yearly').val(0).hide();
        jQuery('.quarterly').val('').show();
    }
})
```

Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/devsaurin/oqkfp06h/3/)